# Query when value trails with .b decreases speed by 30x-100x

Tags: sql-server, database

Consider table `testTable`, a table with six fields: one of them a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, one a TIMESTAMP and four of them VARCHARs. Field `Filename` is VARCHAR.

This first query takes 1 minutes 38 seconds

```
Select top 1 * from testTable WHERE Filename = 'any.string.1512.b'
```

Either of these queries takes  1-3 seconds

```
Select top 1 * from testTable WHERE Filename = 'any.string.1512'

Select top 1 * from testTable WHERE Filename like 'cusip.realloc.1412.b%'
```

I have looked at the execution plan for all three and the only difference is that the last query (the LIKE statement) used 46% index seek\54% Key Lookup vs a 50\50 index\key lookup for the first two. As far as I can tell as soon as I no longer use the `.b` part of this search criterium, the queries go back to normal speed.

`FileName` has been indexed; table has been removed and recreated just in case. We have added indexes, removed indexes, check table, checked database, restart services, restart server, recreated the table. This field used to be VARCHAR(MAX) and I changed it to VARCHAR(100) to index it, but the problem was occurring before making this change.

Something else that I believe may be happening is that there might be something wrong with the end of the table. It will never complete a full:

```
Select * from testTable
```

I hoped it was a corrupted table but that wasn't the case. However when we attempt to generate a script in SSMS it fails to generate (no error given). I was able to recreate it by using another SQL client and generating the structure from SSMS and data copy from the other SQL client.

We are pretty stumped.

Comment: do you use `TOP` without `ORDER BY` ?

Comment: Share `FileName` datatype(size) and default collation. You could also compare `SELECT FileName, LEN(FileName), DATALENGTH(FileName) FROM ...`

Comment: The percentages in the plans are estimates, don't trust them. Look at query plan steps + statistics io output.

Comment: I cant think any reason why first two need different time. can you replace `TOP 1 * ` for `COUNT(*)` are thore result very different?

Comment: Suppose you do the following: `SELECT * INTO newTestTable FROM testTable`. Create an INDEX on `newTestTable.FileName`. Run the queries on `newTestTable`... What happens then? Do you still see a decrease in execution time?

Comment: Select count(*) from testTable; Select count(*) from testTable WHERE Filename = 'any.string.1512.b'; Select count(*) from testTable WHERE Filename = 'any.string.1512'; UPDATE STATISTICS testTable WITH FULLSCAN; I need to know the cardinality of the values in the table, and make sure that the statistics are 100% up to date.

Comment: to TT. that was actually what I did. New table new index run same queries on new table. Same results whenI copied over all the data. if  copied only a  few rows  it worked fine. Table has only about 700 rows though.

Comment: @Lad2025 Filename varchar data type, collation , sql_latin1_general_CP1_CI_AS. 
@ Juan Carlos  I did a count as well. that works fine. However Select * makes it fail.
@ shriop  I  attempted the querys, first 2 ran fast ,3rd took 2 minutes and 4th step ran fine.